# How to make good-looking linkages between single and double bonds in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

The following code produce the molecule shown in the first picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\setchemfig{bond join=true, atom sep=2.5em, bond style={line width=1.pt}}
\chemfig{A-=[:330]B}

\end{document}
```

[image: FirstPicture]

I'd like to know if it's possible to make better looking unions between the single and the double bonds as shown in the second picture.

[image]

Comment: General recommendation regarding screenshots: use formats with lossless compression such as PNG. JP(E)G's lossy compression sometimes adds artifacts that often hinder readability, especially in typography-related cases of applied TeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`chemfig`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) manual, section *Shifted double bonds*:

> All double bonds are made up of two line segments, and these segments are drawn on either side of the imaginary line along which a single bond would be drawn. It is possible to shift a double bond so that one of the line segments lies on the imaginary line. The other segment is then shifted above or below the bond. Actually, it is more correct
> to say “left” or “right” of the imaginary line, as the bond is traversed in the direction of drawing.
>
> To shift the bond to the left, write “`=^`” and to shift it to the right, write “`=_`”:

Applied to your MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
\setchemfig{bond join=true, atom sep=2.5em, bond style={line width=1.pt}}
\chemfig{A-=_[:330]B}
\chemfig{A-=^[:330]B}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Shifted bonds]

P. S. If you want to make the structure look IUPAC-compliant, you need to invest some extra work as your style and `chemfig` defaults are a bit off general recommendations [[1](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200678101897), [2](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277)]. Same goes for the famous "ACS Document 1996" style ([ACS author guidelines (PDF)](https://pubs.acs.org/userimages/ContentEditor/1248420673778/books_authguide.pdf)).

#### References

1. Brecher, J. Graphical Representation of Stereochemical Configuration (IUPAC Recommendations 2006). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2009**, 78 (10), 1897–1970. DOI: [10.1351/pac200678101897](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200678101897). (Free Access)
2. Brecher, J. Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams (IUPAC Recommendations 2008). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2009**, 80 (2), 277–410. DOI: [10.1351/pac200880020277](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277). (Free Access)